# How can a Boron-10 lined detector be used to determine the reactor power pulse in a TRIGA reactor?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrons

I have a Boron-10 lined counter, how can it be used to plot a power vs time curve for a very short period large power excursion?

Comment: Well, start by considering what and how Boron-10 will interact with what happens in a power excursion of a reactor.

Comment: @JonCuster I understand that the neutron interactions will produce counts. But I'm wondering, in current mode operation, how will the signals produced be related to the reactor power?

Comment: More power means more neutrons means more counts (gamma or alpha depending on the detector).